# Android Studio : You got banned permanently from this server in android studio

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using android studio 3.1.2 and using retrofit library for API integration. When I hit any API , I got the response:

**code : 403

message : You got banned permanently from this server.**

I am able to hit api within same network but not outside. I am able to hit api using postman but not from android studio. I have also integrated the code to bypass the certification authentication.

I am hitting the nginx server.

Why is it so? Can anyone help me to get rid of this?

Comment: ask your server dev to clear your user account / or clear requests for ur imei , check what he has blocked.

Comment: What did you do? Why did you get banned xD

Comment: add code here how exactly you are calling API using retrofit

Comment: **Which** API are you querying?

Comment: Previously I was able to hit...After few days I am not able to send. I am using retrofit API version 2.3.0

Comment: I am hitting to nginx server which routes API to get data

Comment: So, you are **querying** an API that is on a Nginx server. Presumably, it belongs to you or your team, so you'll have to deal with them to solve this issue. Voting for close

Comment: But I am able to hit from my postman and ios app also able to hit the server successfully.I was also able to hit before few days.Is there anything missing to enable in android studio?

Comment: No, if you were able to make the exact same requests previously in Android Studio, and all of a sudden you have an access denied, the issue lies on the API you are querying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not adding User-Agent in header so the server refused all my request.Thats why I got banned from the server.

```
return builder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
                        .addInterceptor {
                            val original = it.request();

                            val authorized = original.newBuilder()
                                    .removeHeader("User-Agent")
                                    .addHeader("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"))
                                    .build();

                            it.proceed(authorized);
                        }
                        .build()
```

For better understanding about user-agent, go through this [link](http://cdrussell.blogspot.com/2012/09/programmatically-get-user-agent-string.html).

Comment: this solve and work but still looking where config make the server need the requirement .